# saveAsync fail on subsequent call?

Tags: office-js

I am trying to write an Excel Plugin using the Office Javascript API.  I try to persist settings using the "settings" interface.  As per documentation, I call the saveAsync when I want to save it to desk.  The first time I call the saveAsync function, it seem to work fine.  But on subsequent call, I always get the error "internal error".  Is there anyway to solve this?

This is my helper class to save and persist data:

```
const StorageHelper = {};
StorageHelper.Persist = function (callback) {
    return new OfficeExtension.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        Office.context.document.settings.saveAsync(function (asyncResult) {
            if (asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
                reject("Failed to save data, please contact customer support: " + asyncResult.error.message);
            } else {
                Office.context.document.settings.refreshAsync(function (asyncResult2) {
                    if (callback) callback();
                    resolve();
                });
            }
        });
    });
};
StorageHelper.SaveSettings = function (key, value) {
    Office.context.document.settings.set(key, value);
};
```

Then I try to call it like this:

```
let PassDataType = $("#pass-data-type-select").val();
StorageHelper.SaveSettings("PassDataType", PassDataType);
return StorageHelper.Persist()
    .then(function () {
        ...
    }).catch(function (error) {
        StatusBarHelper.SetMessage(error);
    });
```

I call this code multiple times.  I get this error on every subsequent call.  The first time works fine though.

```
{  
   "status":"failed",
   "error":{  
      "name":"Internal Error",
      "message":"An internal error has occurred.",
      "code":5001
   }
}
```

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your post, Looks like it not repro in my side. i use your code and remove the helper class, but it works just fine in my mac machine. here is the gist for this test, can you share me your gist? i would like to try a local repro. thanks

my gist is here
https://gist.github.com/lumine2008/9ecd9ee661fe64a0ddc02ebfd18c9eef

Comment: Hi raymond, we are in contact with the Microsoft team, and we are getting help from the API team, are you part of the Microsoft API team?  If so, we can forward your name to our contact so we can establish communication formally.

Comment: Yes, i am from Excel API team, Raymond Lu is my name:)